# Is using classes to a single element over an ID just a preference or there would be a complication to it?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In CSS I understand that you use ID if you're targeting a unique element and use classes for general targeting of a group of element. I am maintaining a site where i have to clean up some of the code (html + css), I notice that the previous programmer didn't use any ID for all the element instead he used classes even for unique elements.

So, what's should be an advisable approach, Should I just use classes and follow his coding style, avoid using ID for the elements or should I replace them with IDs and use ID for appropriate elements.

In css, in my understanding, classes can also be used like an ID  where you can just target a single element (eg. .footer vs #footer) and is just a matter of preference.

```
#header { background: #ccc; height: 150px; }
#content { background: red; height: 200px; color: #fff;  }


<div id="header"><h1>Header Area</h1></div>
<div id="content"><h1>Content</h1></div>
<div id="header"><h1>Footer Area</h1></div>
```

notice **#header** was mentioned twice in the id and css rule applies to the two elements.

IDs behaves like Classes (http://jsfiddle.net/79GsY/)

```
.header { background: #ccc; height: 150px; }
.content { background: red; height: 200px; color: #fff;  }
.footer { background: brown; height: 150px; }


<div class="header"><h1>Header Area</h1></div>
<div class="content"><h1>Content</h1></div>
<div class="footer"><h1>Footer Area</h1></div>
```

Notice that there was no ID used here.

Classes behaves like ID (http://jsfiddle.net/qHEJd/)

Please enlighten me with this matter. Thank You.

Comment: I would just go with his style. it's not that big of a matter using class instead of id though

Comment: If it works, don't fix it. Also, consider that right now there may be just one footer in the page, but what about the future? You might have separate sections each with their own footer; in that case, switching from id to classes would be somewhat painful.

Comment: if you have to cleanup the code, a good start it is using semantic markup when available: `<header>, <main>, <footer>`

Comment: There is a small overhead benefit to be gained when you are using IDs for selectors in jQuery - i.e. your site may run marginally faster in people's browsers if you are targeting `$('#header')` instead of `$('.header')`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: If you are writing from scratch, that's a very good idea. If you are "cleaning up", that's a way to do lots of work for absolutely no benefit.

Comment: see this blog post on this issue: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: @jon if the site is built with a modern MVC approach, you should be able to make those markup changes just once

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: And also test them just once, possibly introduce and validate a compatibility shim just once... for what benefit? Don't misunderstand me: it's fine to do this, but not in the context of cleaning up.

Comment: RyandeVries, Jon, I think that's the way to go, I would just adopt his coding style.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, I'm also tempted with that approach but Jon has some point. I would probably do that in the later time if client will go for that route.

Comment: @Doug, Yes, the site is using jQuery, so i'm considering that point too.

Comment: Guys, thank you for sharing your thoughts, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a matter of semantics. You use IDs to identify an element, for instance to distinguish multiple forms on a page, or as link targets. They have a meaning to the markup.

With classes, you set a classification for things, you don't really give them a meaning. It's not like you're grouping them together or anything.

So it's perfectly fine if only one element on a page has a certain class. That doesn't make it "unique".

Comment: Best answer here. + 1. But how is giving things a common classification not grouping them together?

Comment: Because you can give 1 item on a page a class; then you're not really grouping it together with other items. I was trying to respond to the the general idea of "if you have to address multiple elements, use a class, otherwise, use an ID". That's not what the uniqueness according to ID is about.

Answer (score 4):

An ID *must* be unique, a class can be used several times.

Personally I use IDs to *name* different sections of a site. IDs always describe *what* something is, never what it looks like. Examples of common IDs for me are #header, #footer, #post-comment etc.

Classes, on the other hand, are used to categorise similar elements. Both CSS and JS can then target a specific class. Examples of classes are .button, .icon etc.

Personally I don't use classes much at all but prefer to use SASS @mixins as they keep the HTML clean from design related class names.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, there's very little difference between using class names or ID.  There is argument that using an ID in CSS will allow for minutely-faster processing, but it's such a tiny difference to be negligible.

There isn't any reason why you should spend the time modifying the previous developer's markup as long as it is valid (ie: no repetition of IDs) and works.  Modifying classes or IDs/etc may well cause non-desired effects (particularly if the JavaScript is tied to those same DOM elements).

Comment: Yes good point.. that's also something that i am worrying about, that it might be tied to either in the javascript or php somewhere and may result to breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference when it matters if you use `class` or `id` is if you multiple instances of that element. Say, you had a header/content and footer, you know you're going to have only singleton instances of these and so I'd use an `id`.

However, if you have two headers, so:

```
<div id="header></div>
<div id="header></div>
```

This does not comply with HTML standards, and so I'd use:

```
<div class="header></div>
<div class="header></div>
```

In base, if it's a single instance of that element, use an `id`. If you know you're doing the same operation more than once on an element, use a `class`. This is also the standard rule for CSS, to a degree.

Answer (score 0):

You should always keep in mind that **ID's Should be unique** , if you have unique element, you better use `ID`, if not use `class`

quoting from w3c page -

> What makes attributes of type ID special is that no two such
>   attributes can have the same value in a document

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/id_selector

Comment: IDs being unique doesn't mean that you should necessarily use IDs for unique elements. If you use an ID, the element must be unique; the converse (if it's unique, you must use an ID) is not true.

Comment: But i said - if it's unique, you **better** use an ID ,, i never used **must**

Comment: @ pXL: In English, "you better use" basically means "you must use". I think you meant "it's better to use". But I would challenge that statement as well. There's nothing wrong with using classes for unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

The odds of it making any real difference to the site are near zero, so it's up to you. It's a style preference.

I think your question is mainly about the application of CSS styles to the elements, as opposed to scripting. When the CSS is being applied to the elements for styling purposes, I believe it makes literally no difference (other than specificity stuff) whether you use class selectors or ID selectors to specify the styles for the elements. Style application is done by taking the element and matching it against rules, not taking rules and finding elements that match them, if you see what I mean.

On the scripting front, though, for completeness: If you're looking up these elements with jQuery using CSS selectors, an ID selector **may** be ***very marginally*** faster than a class selector to find a single element in a very large document. That's because `$("#someId")` ends up being a call to `document.getElementById` which the browser can do efficiently because it knows that there will only be a single match. In contrast, `$(".someClass")` ends up being a call to `querySelectorAll`, which has to keep searching through the entire document (barring that search having already been cached by the selector engine, of course) even after finding one element, in case there are others.

But again: The odds of it making any real-world difference are virtually nil.

---

And a **very** minor point: Every element with an `id` creates a property on the `window` object with that `id` as its name (e.g., `<div id="foo">` creates a `foo` property on `window`). Creating a lot of properties you're not going to use is a *teensy tiny ipsy little bit* of unnecessary work. ;-) But to call that premature optimization is to dramatically underestimate how premature it is (and dramatically overestimate the amount it optimizes). E.g., this is just trivia. :-)

Comment: jQuery butchers selectors in all sorts of crazy ways according to either the rules of CSS or its own rules all for the sake of performance.

Comment: @BoltClock: My main point is that it really doesn't matter, and certainly not for styling, which seems to be the OP's main concern. Re jQuery: It used to do that, on old browsers. In modern browsers, unless you use jQuery-specific selector extensions, it mostly detects the ID situation and uses `getElementById` or otherwise hands off to `querySelectorAll` (barring various feature detects it has to do for buggy browsers). :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use ID for the Unique element and Classes for the group of element.
Because,

When you are using IDs for the unique element DOM will search Tag with tha ID and will stop its searching as soon as it finds that Tag. 
On the other end if you choose class for the unique element it would work same as IDS but DOM will not stop its searching even after it finds that Tag. It will search the whole page to find any other Tag with that class.

For the Group of Elements, we can't use IDS hence the using Class is the obvious Choice.

Hope this clear your doubt. Let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Note that what you're describing in your second paragraph applies to looking up the elements from script, not the browser applying styles to those elements.